# Horizontal auto-scrolling EditText (not focusable)

Tags: android

There is edit text (or text view, I think that is not important) with options: *focusable="false", focusableInTouchMode="false"*. How to make sure that when you add text to it (programatically add, character by character), which does not fit the whole, the text scrolls to the left? Ie was visible to the end of the text, which fits at edit text?

Comment: not possible as is. textviews don't scroll unless they are focused (that can be assessed by looking at the TextView$Marquee class source code).

Comment: I changed the type of widget TextView and set the following parameters:                       
    <TextView
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"                                  All good, but if the string does not fit entirely, TextView shows ellipsis in the early

Comment: i changed the type of widget from EditText on TextView and used parameter android:inputType="textImeMultiLine" with it. It works how i wanted. But now TextView cuts characters to the left that do not fit entirely